# What does  $\sin^{2k}\theta+\cos^{2k}\theta=$?

Tags: trigonometry

> What is the sum $\sin^{2k}\theta+\cos^{2k}\theta$ equal to?

Besides Mathematical Induction,more solutions are desired.

Comment: you cannot get a simple closed form for that.

Comment: Use complexe numbers: sin x = (exp xi - exp -xi)/2...

Comment: yep,not a simple form:
if k is odd,2^(-2k+2) ( cos2kt + C_2k^2 cos (2k-2)t ...

Comment: @tan9p You don't simply get a closed form of $${\sin ^{2k}}\theta  + {\cos ^{2k}}\theta $$

Comment: To build intuition, try graphing it for k=20. It's a picket fence. Looking at the graph, it's pretty unlikely that it will have a simpler representation than the one already given.

Comment: @Ben Crowell by graphing it for k = 1..7, I thought it would like to converges to a function.but I do not know the exact funtion.

Comment: @Ben Crowell Plot[Sin[x]^(2*{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}) + Cos[x]^(2*{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}) ,{x,0,2Pi}

Comment: Any reason to look at $\sin^{2k}\theta + \cos^{2k}\theta$ instead of $\sin^k\theta + \cos^k\theta$?

Comment: What exactly are you looking for?  Using the power reduction formulas you can always reduce this to a linear combination of $\sin(nx)$ and $\cos(nx)$ for $n$ from 1 to $2k$. Or if you limit $n$ to be smaller, it will be a polynomial. Is this what you want? No doubt you could get some "closed form" in terms of some combanitorial coefficients, but unless $k$ equals 0 or 1 it's not going to drastically simplify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think there is a closed form for all values of $k$, but one can play around with trigonometric identities to simplify the expression for certain values of $k$. For instance:

- If $k=2$, then:

$$\sin^4 x + \cos^4 x = (1-\cos^2 x)^2 + \cos^4 x\\
= 1-2\cos^2x + 2\cos^4 x \\
= 1-2\cos^2x(1-\cos^2x)\\
= 1-2\sin^2x\cos^2x\\
= 1 - \frac{\sin^2(2x)}{2}.$$

- If $k=3$, then:

$$\sin^6 x + \cos^6 x = (1-\cos^2 x)^3 + \cos^6 x\\
= 1-3\cos^2x + 3\cos^4 x - \cos^6 x + \cos^6 x \\
= 1-3\cos^2x + 3\cos^4x\\
= 1-3\cos^2x(1-\cos^2x)\\
= 1-3\sin^2x\cos^2x\\
= 1 - \frac{3\sin^2(2x)}{4}.$$

Comment: thank you,but I want to generalized.

Answer (score 1):

If you let $z_k=\cos^k(\theta)+i\sin^k(\theta)\in\Bbb C$, it is clear that
$$
\cos^{2k}(\theta)+\sin^{2k}(\theta)=||z_k||^2.
$$
When $k=1$ the complex point $z_1$ describes (under the usual Argand-Gauss identification $\Bbb C=\Bbb R^2$) the circumference of radius $1$ centered in the origin, and your expression gives $1$.

For any other value $k>1$, the point $z_k$ describes a closed curve $\cal C_k\subset\Bbb R^2$ and your expression simply computes the square distance of the generic point from the origin. There's no reason to expect that this expression may take a simpler form than it already has.

Comment: The original problem is to discuss the Range of the function f(x) = cos^{2k}\theta + sin^{2k}\theta.

Comment: Wait, you need to know the range of $f(x)$? That is not what you asked in your original post!

Comment: yeah,but I thought I'd get the range if I know the exact form.

Comment: If you want the range of $f(\theta)=\cos^{2k}(\theta)+\sin^{2k}(\theta)$ a useful intermediate step may be finding the points where $df/d\theta=0$.

Comment: you are right,the calculus is a good method.